# Address/ports keep becoming stuck on ubuntu (server) - even after the process terminates

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, process, netstat

I'm having an issue on a headless Ubuntu 18.04 installation. Ports keep becoming "stuck" which is either preventing processes from terminating (even when sending a `SIGKILL`), or allowing the processes to terminate and then sitting there in an irreversibly bound state. This seems to happen especially when stopping/restarting system services, and when it does, the address is already in use, and so the service cannot restart successfully.

Here is an example output when trying to deduce whether there are any processes remaining which are bound to a particular port:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 12345
tcp        7      0 0.0.0.0:12345            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Notice that the `PID/Program name` is empty (`-`). This is the case regardless of how the command is run: as the user, through `sudo`, or even as root.

Notice also the `7` here (in the `RECV-Q` column). It seems to consistently be the case that some data is stuck, waiting to be consumed by the process, but the process has already terminated.

Occasionally, the process will hang around and refuse to terminate, even when trying every known method of sending a `SIGKILL` to it. I can't reproduce this reliably, though.

I have observed this happening with multiple services. I don't think it's an issue in the implementation of whatever is binding to the ports.

Thoughts?